# Single underscore as unused variable name in function signature?

Tags: c, naming-conventions

I am building an interface in C which defines some function types with predefined signatures. Some implementations of this interface may not use some of the passed variables.

Is it a good / reasonable practice to use a Python-style single underscore in implementations that don't use certain arguments? The purpose is readability, but I don't know if that would confuse other devs reading the code even more.

E.g.:

```
// Interface definition

typedef int (*do_something_fn_t)(int a, float b);

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    do_something_fn_t do_something_fn;
} MyInterface;


// Implementation

int complex_calculation (int a, float _)
{ return a + 1; }

const MyInterface super_useful_int = {
    .name = "Super useful interface",
    .do_something_fn = complex_calculation,
};
```

Comment: Personally, I'd give it a name like "unused".  And then at the top of the function, to silence compiler warnings about an unused variable, I'd throw in `(void) unused;`

Comment: I'd perhaps use `unused` instead - or enable the next C standard with `-std=c2x` and remove the identifier completely: `int complex_calculation (int a, float)`

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate here.  This question is asking about a good naming convention for an unused variable, which the author incidentally is currently using `_`, but the underscore really isn't at the crux of the question.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yes, closing it for likely attracting opinion based answers would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oops. Fixed.

Comment: I think it's wiser to keep the name of the unused parameter; if it's named properly it carries information that you may want to get when you study the function in isolation, even if the parameter is unused. For example, a function used for calculating the number of elements in a sequence, reduction style, may have the signature `int Increment(int accumulator, int element)` and then when you see that the second parameter is the current element it is easier to understand why it is unused.